# Unable to load file or assembly 'microsoft.asp,netcore.dataprotection.abstractions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019, rdlc

I am currently working on an Asp.net web (.net v4.8) solution and need to use RDLC to display some data to the end-users,
I have installed `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewControl.WebForms` & `Microsoft.SQLServer.Types` NuGet packages to the solution, along with **Microsoft RDLC Report Designer** & **Microsoft Reporting Services Projects** Visual studio extensions for VS2019.

When opening a report to design and select a new Data source I am greeted with the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0.
> ...... The system cannot find the file specified,

I have tried deleting the `bin` & `obj` folder as suggested by other solutions
Uninstalling the NuGet packages and reinstalling along with the extensions

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: What’s the target framework?

Comment: hi the target framework is .net v4.8

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the error that appears? There should be a suggestion link above. [Did you operate correctly?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017#adding-the-report-viewer-control-to-a-new-windows-forms-project)